# Unable to cast object of type ‘Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.EdiExt.ComboItem’ to type ‘System.String’ error in BizTalk Server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I got the following error while setting up an EDI profile for a trading partner in BizTalk Server 2013.

> Unable to cast object of type ‘Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.EdiExt.ComboItem’ to type ‘System.String’. (Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.EdiExt)

No matter what I do, it never goes away. What can I do to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumble upon this page in future, I found a workaround on this [blog](https://integrationadventures.wordpress.com/2014/12/03/is-it-a-bug-in-biztalk-server-2013/). The trick is to keep clicking APPLY button after every field change.

Apparently it seems a UI bug in the product which has been patched up by Microsoft till now. Microsoft has also provided a patch [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/4230298/microsoft-biztalk-administration-ediext-comboitem-saving-edifact-x12) for BizTalk Server.

**Update:** The patch from Microsoft is for BizTalk Server 2016.

Comment: Except that patch is for BizTalk 2016 (and is in CU5) whereas you are using BizTalk 2013 according to your question.  We can hope they release it for earlier version at some point

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer accordingly.